# Google conversion tracking in Magento Fooman/Inchoo

Tags: extensions, google-api

we use Google Analytics+ from Fooman to track in google analytics.

http://store.fooman.co.nz/magento-extension-googleanalyticsplus.html

Now we want to really track the conversions also. There is a field in the extension from Fooman that says: conversion Id, but this does not seem to work.

On the other hand I see this extension from Inchoo that seems to focus on the conversion

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-and-google-adwords-conversion-tracking/comment-page-1/#comment-54344

Question: 
Is there an extension that does both/all in one?

And of not, would I need to install both extension separately to be complete? or does Fooman's extension also support the latter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our extension should be able to track the Adwords conversion for you. To set it up please make sure to copy both the Conversion ID and Label to the corresponding settings from this page:

[image: Conversion ID and Label]

Once that is confirmed please don't hesitate to email us the source html of your success page to further look into this.

Comment: Superb! Sory - this just wasn't clear. And to make you laugh: our team thought the LABEL field in backend was "just a label" (as in a short name). Now we pasted the second value in this field. Lets see how it works out.

Comment: If it is any consolation you aren't the only one to miss this - the above is from an upcoming update to the manual so hopefully that will make this clearer in the future.

Comment: May I ask: would it also be possible to ad facebook conversion tracking to this extension? It seems the processes is quite similar. And what I have read it seems only some cod eis needed on the success page.

Comment: Possible is everything - but I believe in keeping extensions specialised and limited in scope so would rather see this as a separate extension that offers this.

Comment: May be this will help to your facebook question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23244945/facebook-conversion-tracking-in-magento